# Return statement doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, image, indentation

So I was working with this line of code to convert an input image into an URL, however, the return doesn't seem to be working as I can't access the constant anywhere else in the document where I actually need it.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
                    return imageURL;
                }
            });
          });
```

I'm still new to JavaScript so for the life of me I can't find why it doesn't work, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where u use Jquery. This is vanila javascript

Comment: You should use here a global variable to store image url.

Comment: The thing that fires the event and calls your event listener function doesn't care what your function returns.  [According to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#getting_data_into_and_out_of_an_event_listener) the return value is ignored.  So `return imageURL` doesn't accomplish anything.  You probably don't want to just `return` the `imageURL`, rather, you want to call another callback function and pass it the imageURL -- that callback should do what should happen in response to this event now that you've created the Object URL.

Answer (score 0):

That's because constant imageURL is scoped in if block, if you want it to be accessed in whole file declare it outside addEventListener() function. For e.g.

```
let imageURL;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
                    
                }
            });
          });

console.log(imageURL)
```